# Is "scalar electromagnetics" real science?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity

[This page](http://www.cheniere.org/books/aids/ch4.htm) claims that original Maxwell's equations, when formulated by Maxwell himself in quaternion form, had some special scalar part of electromagnetic field, which somehow appeared to describe gravitation. The author says that further development of this is called "scalar electromagnetics" or, as Soviets are claimed to have called it, "energetics".

While I read that page, my gut feeling tells me this is all nonsense. But am I right? I've tried googling for this term, and found some antiscientific sites, and nothing like that in any respectable sources like science journals or wikipedia. So, is this really some real science, or is it antiscientific trash? If it's for real, are there any credible sources to read more about this?

Comment: Sounds like nonsense to me :)

Comment: Check it against the criteria for pseudoscience. Does the author try to invalidate his hypothesis by checking it agains observed facts? Does he appeal to authority rather than making strong arguments? Does he have a prosecution complex?

Comment: Related question at electronics.se: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/160051/is-the-scalar-wave-phenomenon-real-and-if-so-why-is-it-not-much-in-practical-u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation. That being said, it sounds like nonsense to me as well. I found some attempts to debunk it on rational wiki,

http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Scalar_wave

It's not the most neutral article, but I think it may help you sort out fact from fiction. I think the treatment in the "In real physics" section seems mostly spot on.